# Closing ASPxPopupControl and Reset Login Dialogs

Tags: controls, authentication, user-controls, devexpress

I am creating a login usercontrol. I have added the following buttons: Recover Password, Change Password & Edit Profile.

I am using DevExpress's ASPxPopupControl to host the functions associated with those three buttons.

There are two problems

1. When the popup is opened I need to be able to close/hide it using a command button
2. When a user starts using one of the login controls and chooses to close the dialog the next time the dialog is opened it does not start at the beginning. 
   (e.g. Start the change password dialog, enter some information, close the popup; the information you started with is not cleared)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to help you with closing the popup on a keypress.  You can use the Escape key as in this example or code your own.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q209168.aspx

For resetting the values, it appears this is manual.

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q252942.aspx